# what's wrong with my jquery toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, toggle

i have div which its id is: 
manufacturer_63...
its style is: display:none, visibility:hidden.

what i've written is:

```
$('select.styled2').change(function() {

     var id = this.value;

            $.ajax({
              type: "GET",
              url: 'index.php?act=manufacturerHome&id='+id,
              success: function(data) {

                $("#manufacturer_"+id).html(data);
              }
            });

     $("#manufacturer_"+id).css('visibility','visible');
     $("#manufacturer_"+id).toggle("slow");

});
```

it does not toggles it.
if i try to:

```
 $("#manufacturer_"+id).css('display','block');
```

instead of toggle - it works.

if i do just toggle of something it works.

Comment: Have you tried to just use slideDown('slow') instead of toggle('slow')? Your intention is to show the element, not toggle it.

Comment: Can we see your CSS and HTML also? I built a quick version of your code above and the toggle works. http://jsfiddle.net/7QnCj/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really be doing this:

```
$('select.styled2').change(function() {
    var id = this.value;

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: 'index.php?act=manufacturerHome&id='+id,
        success: function(data) {
            $("#manufacturer_"+id).html(data);
            $("#manufacturer_"+id).css('visibility','visible');
            $("#manufacturer_"+id).toggle("slow");
        }
    });
});
```

In your code, the element will be shown regardless whether or not the ajax call is finished whereas this will show the element only after the ajax call is successful.

As an aside, you don't need both `display: none` and `visibility: hidden`. Just `display: none` will suffice and you can then get rid of `$("#manufacturer_"+id).css('visibility','visible');`.